# passing variable in another controller

Tags: java, javafx, controller, scenebuilder

Hello i am making a javafx program and i run into a problem:
i pass a variables value here in another controller with this

```
    buttonSignIn.setOnAction(e -> {
        try {
            User user = new User();
            user.setUsername(userName.getText().trim());
            user.setPassword(password.getText().trim());


            if (DB.validateLogin(user)){
                // change scene if this is true
                userId = DB.getUserId(user);
                System.out.println("Controller: users name: "+user.getUsername()+"users id: "+ userId);

                buttonSignIn.getScene().getWindow().hide();
                FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
                loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/sample/view/user.fxml"));
                loader.load();

                Parent root = loader.getRoot();
                Stage stage = new Stage();
                stage.setScene(new Scene(root));

                UserController userController = loader.getController();
                userController.setUserId(userId);

                stage.showAndWait();

            }else{
                System.out.println("please type your username and password");

            }

        }catch (Exception ex){
            System.out.println("problem ..."+ ex);
        }
    });
```

i pass it at "userController"
code in userController:
in the initialize method i have

```
usersLabel.setText(" users id is : "+getUserId());
System.out.println("User controller: users id is : "+ getUserId());
```

and outside initialize i have the getters and setters

```
public void setUserId(int id) {
    this.userId = id;
    System.out.println("User controller: users controller : "+userId);
    System.out.println("User controller: what is this?"+ getUserId());
}



public  int getUserId(){

    return userId;
}
```

and the results i get are

- Controller: users name: billusers id: 1
- User controller: users id is:0
- User controller: users controller : 1
- User controller: what is this?1

i wanna set the label with the correct value of userId but the value within initialize is 0 instead of any number where the id is, in this case it was 1

Comment: Set the label text in the `setUserId(...)` method...

Comment: oh.. yea idk why i didn't think of that.. thanks!